# javascript setTimeout() first argument: expression error

Tags: javascript, time, settimeout

```
function Timer() {
 this.initialTime = 0;
 this.timeStart = null;

 this.getTotalTime = function() {
  timeEnd = new Date();
  diff = timeEnd.getTime() - this.timeStart.getTime();

  return diff+this.initialTime;
 };

 this.formatTime = function() {
  interval = new Date(this.getTotalTime());

  return  interval.getHours() + ":" +  interval.getMinutes() + ":" + interval.getSeconds();
 };

 this.start = function() {
  this.timeStart = new Date();

  setTimeout("this.updateTime()", 1000);
 };

 this.updateTime = function() {
  alert(this.formatTime());
  setTimeout("this.updateTime()", 1000);
 };
}


timer = new Timer();
timer.start();
```

I am getting an error:

> this.updateTime is not a function

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I wonder if we can/should change this question to be a very generic one. All the code in the question didn't help me, I just went straight to the answer :).

Comment: Turns out, `setTimeout` with a string as its first argument behaves like an _indirect_ eval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string is not evaluated in the context of your object, so `this` doesn't refer to what you think it does.

You should not be passing a string argument to `setTimeout`. Instead, you should pass an anonymous function that calls your method with a saved copy of `this`.

For example:

```
var self = this;
setTimeout(function() { self.updateTime(); }, 1000);
```

The `self` variable is necessary because `setTimeout`'s callback is also not evaluated in the context of your object.

Comment: this works but.. is there a more elegant way? Without defining the global variable?

Comment: That's a local, not a global.  You could use a proxy function.

Comment: Ok.. I'm not a JS expert by any means.  Thanks!

Comment: `self` is a regular local variable.  Because the anonymous function is in the same scope, it saves references to all the local variables.  This is an extremely powerful feature called a closure.

Comment: Actually, if you define `self` inside the `updateTime` function, it's not guaranteed to refer to the `Timer` object either. There is no difference between your code and a direct `setTimeout(this.updateTime)`. `this`/`self` have the same context. :)

Comment: @deceze: You are wrong.  The difference is in the invocation of updateTime.

Comment: Exactly. `this` depends on how the function is invoked. `self` will be equal to `this`. It may work if the `Timer` object is calling functions on itself, but it can break if you invoke the function in a way that causes `this` to change to something else.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
var me = this;
setTimeout(function() { me.updateTime() }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

> is there a more elegant way?

Yes, in ECMAScript Fifth Edition:

```
setTimeout(this.updateTime.bind(this), 1000);
```

However, until all browsers support Fifth Edition (which they don't yet by a long measure), you should add your own implementation of Function.bind as fallback. eg.:

```
// Add ECMA262-5 method binding if not supported natively
//
if (!('bind' in Function.prototype)) {
    Function.prototype.bind= function(owner) {
        var that= this;
        if (arguments.length<=1) {
            return function() {
                return that.apply(owner, arguments);
            };
        } else {
            var args= Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
            return function() {
                return that.apply(owner, arguments.length===0? args : args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
            };
        }
    };
}
```

You might also prefer to use `setInterval` to avoid the repeated `setTimeout` calls. Finally, you should remember to declare all your variables (`timeEnd`, `diff`, etc.) as `var`, otherwise you're getting accidental globals, which can cause you horrible debugging heartache.

Answer (score 0):

If you supply a string to `setTimeout`, this string will be executed literally. The thing is, it will be executed sometime later in the global context, outside your `Timer` object, so `this` means something completely different.

Just pass the function itself like so:

```
function Timer() {
  var self = this;   // make reference to this that won't change with context

  this.updateTime = function() {
    alert(self.formatTime());
    setTimeout(self.updateTime, 1000);
  };

}
```