# Can't get syntax correct for dynam. create onclick the ie way

Tags: javascript, function, dynamic, onclick, insertion

I was hoping to keep cross-browser compatibility and afaik this is the only issue so far.

```
.setAttribute("onclick", "return showRapidText("+itemnum+");");
```

This works PERFECT but I'd like to make it IE compatible by putting it in this syntax

```
.onclick = new Function("fnDisplay_Computers('" + alines[i] + "')");
```

so... I tried

```
.onclick = new Function("showRapidText('" + itemnum + "')");
```

and

```
.onclick = new Function("return showRapidText('" + itemnum + "')");
```

and about 40 other ways but nothing works

Comment: Thank you for both your answers and your right that I was trying to do this in a loop so that first answer didn't workout for my problem. What I ended up doing that works like a charm is this.
xxx.setAttribute("itemnum",itemnum);
xxx.onclick = function() { return showRapidText(this.getAttribute("itemnum")); };

This answer was provided by a very nice and brilliant member of codingforums by the name of Old Pendant.

Answer (score 3):

```
element.onclick = function() {
    return showRapidText(itemnum);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

+1 J-P's answer: function literals are massively better than strings. Hacking together code in strings is a horror you should avoid at all costs. Also `setAttribute` should almost never be used in an HTMLDocument due to IE compatibility (and because DOM Level 1 HTML properties are more readable anyway).

One potential trap though: if you are doing this in a loop, which it looks as if you are, you won't get the behaviour you want, due to the [closure loop problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643542/doesnt-javascript-support-closures-with-local-variables). You can solve this with another closure:

```
for (var i= 0; i<alines.length; i++) {
    elements[i].onclick= function(i) {
        return function() {
            fnDisplay_Computers(alines[i]);
        };
    }(i);
}
```

or more cleanly by using the ECMAScript Fifth Edition feature `Function#bind`:

```
for (var i= 0; i<alines.length; i++) {
    elements[i].onclick= fnDisplay_Computers.bind(null, alines[i]);
}
```

[Adding Function#bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604597/javascript-settimeout-first-argument-expression-error/2606471#2606471) to browsers that don't yet support it.